# tikz matrix keep spaces in text

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a tikz matrix

```
 row1 & a  b  c  & d  e  f \\
 row2 & 1  12 16 & 34 2  55 \\
 ....
```

and I need to keep the spacing correct(basically use a monospaced font) for correctly alignment between rows.

I can't make each letter into it's own column because it will mess up the total matrix(which is more complex than the example above). Some columns will not have to be spaced like this. I could possibly make the whole matrix monospaced though if it will preserve spacing?

I've tried `\verbatim` but I get errors. The

Comment: Is it a `matrix of nodes`?  Will `every node/.style={font=\ttfamily}` as an option to the matrix do?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. This doesn't seem to preserve to more than one space. (e.g., it keeps `a b c ` aligned with `1 2 3 ` but not `a  b  c  ` with `11 22 33 `)

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't, as it's not verbatim. Plain `\verb|1  2  3|` works, but I don't know how to set that for all cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution. It uses *typewriter* font to ensure that all characters have the same width. Furthermore instead of normal spaces () you can used protected spaces (`~`). Without options, the cells are aligned centered, you need to align them left by specifying `right` (e.g. make them *starting left and growing to the right*). The `draw` option was only set to illustrate the dimension of the individual cells.

### Code

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes,nodes={font=\ttfamily,draw,right}]
{   row1 & a~~b~~c  & d~~e~f \\
    row2 & 1~~12~16 & 34~2~55 \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Result

[image]